# OG assign existing content to group

Tags: organic-groups

I'm adding OG to and existing site with hundreds of existing nodes. I'm looking for a way to assign existing content to groups. Sort of OG after-the-fact. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [og_group](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_group/7) provided by the OG module.

```
  // The id of the group to which you need to assign the nodes
  $gid = 123;

  // The node which should be added to a group.
  $node = node_load(1);

  $values = array(
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'entity' => $node,
    'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE,
  );

  //Add the current node to the group using the funciton provided by OG
  $result = og_group('node', $gid, $values);
```